# Check if a value is duplicate in a group of values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table where I have many rows with their ids in groups of 2, and another column with one value associated that can be there ("X" value) or not:

| ID | Flag_value |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| A |  |
| B | X |
| B |  |
| C |  |
| C | X |
| D | X |
| D | X |

What I want to do is to check if there are any cases where the X value is associated to the same ID twice. In this case, this only happens for D (both of the ids have an "X"), but not for A,B or C. Having a lot of rows, is there a way of doing this with a formula? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=unique(filter(A2:A;map(A2:A;lambda(z;countifs(B2:B;"X";A2:A;z)))>1))
```

[image]